# Pythonの出力の表示についてです

Tags: python, python3

**一つ**
以下で挙げたように、時々刻々と繰り返しのアウトプットをする関数を作ったとします。その出力結果を毎回上書きして表示させることはできますか？
つまりPythonの出力ログだと縦に結果が表示されますが、自分がやりたいのはインベーダーゲームの、敵キャラみたいな感じで、光線が伸びていくような表示にしたいのです。どうすればよいでしょうか？

**二つ**
仮にこのモジュールを一体の敵と見立てた時に、インベーダーゲームというからには画面には複数の敵が欲しいです。
行ごとにモジュールを配置して、同じ画面内に表示しつつ、独立に動かすことは可能ですか？それはどのようなコードでしょうか

資料映像：[スペースインベーダー (YouTube)](https://youtu.be/MLSSxLe_AFE)

```
import time

def Enemy():
    enemy=[["@","*"],["@","-","*"],["@","-","-","*"],["@","-","-","-","*"],["@","-","-","-","-","*"],["@","-","-","-","-","-","*"]]

    N=0
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        print(enemy[N])
        N=(N+1)%6
        
Enemy()
```

Comment: キャラクタ表示でゲームのような画面上を目一杯使って動作するプログラムを作る際にはこちらが良いのでは？ [curses --- 文字セル表示を扱うための端末操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/curses.html) アクションとかは無いですが使用例 [terminally_bored_terminal_board_games/minesweeper.py](https://github.com/salt-die/terminally_bored_terminal_board_games/blob/master/minesweeper.py)

Comment: Pythonの出力画面のコンソールでこういった動的なゲームを作るのは難しいと思います。KivyなどのGUIライブラリを活用して作るか、他の言語や開発環境(たとえばUnityなど)を選択するのが良いのではないかと思います。Kivyでゲームを制作するサンプルコード集が以下URL(https://qiita.com/dario_okazaki/items/63a721d6aa3fa7ea452b)

Comment: 参考: [Space-Invaders: a terminal-based arcade game](https://github.com/preet021/Space-Invaders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 一つ
> 以下で挙げたように、時々刻々と繰り返しのアウトプットをする関数を作ったとします。その出力結果を毎回上書きして表示させることはできますか？

エスケープシーケンスを解する端末で実行するなら、以下のコードで上書き表示できます。

```
        print('\x1b[1;1H', end='') #カーソルを1行1桁目に設定
        print('\x1b[2K', end='')   #行末までクリア
        print(enemy[N])
```

本格的にプログラミングするのであればCursesを使う方がよいでしょう。
[Python で Curses プログラミング](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/curses.html)
※リンク先は`https://docs.python.org/ja/3/howto/curses.html`です。

> 二つ
> 仮にこのモジュールを一体の敵と見立てた時に、インベーダーゲームというからには画面には複数の敵が欲しいです。
> 行ごとにモジュールを配置して、同じ画面内に表示しつつ、独立に動かすことは可能ですか？それはどのようなコードでしょうか

カーソル(文字列の表示開始位置)を移動して描画することを繰り返せば、できなくはないと思いますが、きっと大変です。